# How do I order results by hstore attribute in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hstore

How can I order query results by an hstore attribute?

```
@items = Item.includes(:product).order('products.properties @> hstore("platform")')
```

Causes

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "platform" does not exist
LINE 1: ...oduct_id"  ORDER BY products.properties @> hstore("platform"...
```

`platform` is a hstore key, stored in the properties column, which is an hstore type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Double quotes are used to quote identifiers (such as table and column names) in PostgreSQL (and other databases that follow the standard). So when you say:

```
hstore("platform")
```

PostgreSQL sees `"platform"` as a quoted column name and since there is no `platform` column, you get an error.

Strings in standard SQL are quoted with single quotes, you want to say:

```
.order("products.properties @> hstore('platform')")
```

This will probably still fail though, `hstore('platform')` doesn't make much sense and neither does using `@>` here; [`a @> b`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE) means

> does the hstore `a`  contain the hstore `b`

If you're trying to sort on the value of the `'platform'` key in the `properties` hstore then you'd want to use `->` to lookup the `'platform'` key like this:

```
.order("products.properties -> 'platform'")
```